# Prove that this triangle is equilateral?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given  $\triangle ABC$. Let $D$  be the point where the altitude form the $A$ vertex intersect $\overline{BC}$ and the point $E$ is the intersect between the bisector of $\angle ABC$ with $\overline{AC}$. Let $P$ be the point of intersect of $\overline{AD}$ with $\overline{BE}$.

Prove that if $AP=2PD$ and  $BP=2PE$, then  $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral.

[image: Diagram]

This is essentially what I've tried. But I don't know how to continue, I can't find any useful congruences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Angle Bisector Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) in $\triangle ABD$, 
$$\frac{|BA|}{|BD|} = \frac{|PA|}{|PD|} = \frac{2}{1}$$
Therefore, $\triangle ABD$ is a $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle; and, then, so is $\triangle BPD$. This implies that your single-tick-mark segments are congruent to your double-tick-mark segments, so that $\triangle APE \cong \triangle BPD$ (SAS). The conclusion follows.

Comment: How can you know $\triangle ABD$ is a 30∘-60∘-90∘ triangle ?

Comment: @user143201: $\triangle ABD$ is a right triangle whose hypotenuse is twice as long as one of its legs. That only happens for $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangles. :)

Answer (score 2):

If AP = 2PD and BP = 2PE, then P is the centroid. ….(#)

From (#), AD is then served both as the median and altitude. This further implies AB = AC. …. (%)

From (#), BE is then served both as the median and angle bisector.

By bisector theorem BA : BC = AE : EC = 1 : 1, meaning that BA = BC. ….(@)

(%) + (@) implies  △ABC is equilateral.

Comment: Why must $P$ be the centroid? You do not know about $CP:PF$.

Comment: If I prove P is the in-center first, will that be sufficient to say P is the centroid?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that $AB \parallel DE$.

**Hint:** Show that $BD=DE= \frac{AB}{2}$.

**Hint:** Show that $\angle ABD = 60^\circ$.

Define $C^*$ on $BC$ such that $ABC^*$ is an equilateral triangle.

**Hint:** Show that $P$ is the centroid of $ABC^*$.

Use the fact that $BP = 2 PE$ to conclude that $C=C^*$.

Comment: How can I show that $AB||DE$ , Thanks!!

Comment: @user143201 Follows directly from the ratio of sides being 2:1.